# Unable to see agreement page for public wifi on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

I am currently using a Xoom tablet to post a question because my Windows 7 laptop is unable to pull up a page for a public wifi network asking me to agree to their terms before gaining a Internet access. This is a 
fresh Windows 7 install with all of my required drivers.

My ipconfig /all shows I am connected to the wifi with a default gateway of 192.168.127.254

I'm unsure what I should investigate the to determine the cause.

Comment: Where are you expecting to see an agreement page? What happens when you open a browser and try to go a common site such as `google.com`?

Comment: @Moab I haven't tried IE... I'll give that a shot next time I'm there.

Comment: @iglvzx - I expect `google.com` to load the agreement page, but it sits there trying to load before throwing a browser timeout page or something that tells me to check my proxy settings.

Comment: @moab that worked, please submit that as an answer so I can choose it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which browser are you using?, I had this issue with Chrome, opened IE and then could see the agreement page, agreed using IE, then Chrome could be used to surf.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue. Removed my DNS server config. Set to use the router for DNS. Turns out that the agreement was not an IP but resolved by DNS, which is why it did not work. Accepted agreement. Put DNS server settings back after, and it all worked.